# Page indexing issues detected: robots.txt fetch failed

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

I got an email from Google Search Console Team sc-noreply@google.com, saying:

```
Page indexing issues detected in http://sprechcomputer.de/

To the owner of http://MYDOMAIN.de/:

Search Console has identified that your site is affected by 1 Page indexing issue(s). The following issues were found on your site. We recommend that you fix these issues when possible to enable the best experience and coverage in Google Search.

Top issues

    Crawled - currently not indexed

Fix Paging Issues
```

I visited Search Console, and it said:
"robots.txt fetch failed"
You have a robots.txt file taht we are currently unable to fetch. In such cases we stop crawling your sited until we get hold of a robots.txt, or fall back to the last known good robots.txt file.

I visited my website, but it doesn't have a robots.txt file, and to my knowledge, it never had.

How do I fix this problem?

In search console, I tried to investigate the problem further:

[image]

And then I see this:

[image]

My server looks like this:

[image]

Comment: *"I visited my website, but it doesn't have a `robots.txt` file, and to my knowledge, it never had."* - have you tried to make one? a very permissive one or just for telling where the sitemap is. google has a guide for making one, [see docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/create-robots-txt).

Comment: @BagusTesa Creating one was my last option. I would like to know what is happening here. It never asked me for one before, so I am afraid there is something problematic going on, and I want to find out what.

Comment: is your site a static one served using apache? if the `robots.txt` file doesn't exists it should return a 404 **Page Not Found** error, not a site broken one (500) which your site did - [see http status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). something is broken but definitely not on google's part.

Comment: anyway, i tried to search for `sprechcomputer.de` on google and it still appear on it. so your site is definitelly still indexed, even though not having `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`. lucky (or pretty old site with a lot of incoming links) i'd say.

Comment: @BagusTesa Wow, you put my nose into a big problem. Thank you! It's resolved now.